# Link for Meta Stack Exchange in dropdown not working?

Tags: support, top-bar, stack-exchange-button

Choosing the Meta Stack Exchange link in the site dropdown takes you to this site, Meta Stack Overflow.  Lets fix that please.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The dropdown itself links to http://meta.stackexchange.com just fine, but your browser cached the 301 permanent redirect that was in place before the MSO-MSE split.

So when you click on the link, your *browser* will redirect you to http://meta.stackoverflow.com instead without checking with the server.

You'll need to clear your browser cache.

[Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6980192/firefox-5-caching-301-redirects) is specifically susceptible to this, but Internet Explorer and Chrome can also still have the redirect cached.

Comment: Thanks, I'll leave this up for others who may have that problem.

Comment: In IE11 I opened up the Network tab in the Developer tools and in the toolbar selected `Always refresh from server` because clearing the cache didn't work...

Comment: @user1306322: what browser are you using?

Comment: nvm found the solution for firefox: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12796598/1306322